# pre-commit.com: Same version in .pre-commit-config.yaml and requirements.txt

Tags: pre-commit.com

I would like to use the exactly same version of flake8 in `requirements.txt` and in `.pre-commit-config.yaml`.

To avoid redundancy I would like to keep the version number of flake8 exactly once in my repo.

Can pre-commit.com read the version number of flake8 from `requirements.txt`?

Comment: Related: https://browniebroke.com/blog/gh-action-pre-commit-autoupdate/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it cannot

pre-commit intentionally does not read from the repository under test as this makes caching intractable

you can read more in [this issue](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/issues/730) and the many duplicate issues linked there

for me, I no longer include flake8, etc. in my requirements files as pre-commit **replaces** the need to install linters / code formatters elsewhere

---

disclaimer: I created pre-commit

Comment: I know this seems like a closed issue on the part of the lib creator, but to be fair pre-commit doesn't really "replace" the need to install linters - eg. we run our checks on CI, where pre-commit does not make sense, and it should run regardless of what the user has installed on his local machine (eg. his precommit install is wrong/broken/bypassed). This means having versions on requirements.txt + config.yaml, which is painful to maintain (eg. having to manually update dependabot PRs)

Comment: pre-commit works great as a CI tool, so yes it does