# How to specify path to a local reposiory in .pre-commit-config.yaml?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I have a local package `B` which depends on another local package `A`. They both are stored in a company repository: `https://mycompany.com/api/pypi/pypi-bld/simple`. Therefore, tests of  `B` requires `A`.

I need to use pre-commit which uses both the company repository and the default one.
I use this `.pre-commit-config.yaml`, where I have black, pre-commit-hooks, flake8 and init tests:

```
repos:
  - repo: https://github.com/psf/black
    some parameters...
  - repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    some parameters...
  - repo: https://github.com/pycqa/flake8
    some parameters...
  - repo: local
    hooks:
      - id: unittest
        name: unittest
        entry: python -m unittest discover
        language: python
        language_version: "3.9"
        "types": [python]
        pass_filenames: false
        stages: [commit]
        additional_dependencies: ['--index-url', 'https://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@mycompany.com/api/pypi/pypi-bld/simple',
                                  'requests', 'mylocal-package']
```

As you can see there is credential information. It is dangerous. So, how to specify in a more clever way? Maybe it is possible to specify a custom `pip` from `virtualenv` for `pre-commit`?

Comment: Also, I found out that pre-commit intentionally does not read from the repository under test as this makes caching intractable `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65940222/pre-commit-com-same-version-in-pre-commit-config-yaml-and-requirements-txt`. So it can be very hard to reach what I want

Comment: running tests as part of pre-commit is a bad idea -- it's too slow (pre-commit should be for very fast checks only).  otherwise your contributors will get frustrated and turn the whole thing off

Comment: for me, it was ok, before splitting a big package into `A` and `B`. pre-commit took less than a minute. It is ok, in comparison with the time of code development.

Comment: alright glhf -- I'm not going to encourage a bad idea so you're on your own

Comment: you didn't explain why it is a bad idea, of course, I have blake, flake8 etc, but I have hidden them. My unit tests are very fast and committing is rare, (1 or 2 times per day), I don't want to refuse this idea due to the expenses of 10-20 sec per day:)

Comment: I 100% did explain you just chose to ignore it

Comment: the answer that it is not possible can satisfy me.